# Volley RequestQueue: retry after noConnectionError

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I try to implement a simple asynchronous http request, pushing some data to server and work with the response.
But sometime the smartphone is getting out of network access and StringRequest stops with a noConnectionError. The Request seems to be finished then and retry rules do not apply (no retry is being done, regardless if i add my own retryrules or not).

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://myurl/test.php",
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                // Do something with the response
                Toast.makeText(context, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // Handle error
                Toast.makeText(context, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }

    @Override
    protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "parseNetworkError");
        return super.parseNetworkError(volleyError);
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverError(final VolleyError error) {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "deliverError");
    }
};
stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new MyRetryPolicy(20 * 1000, 5, 1.0f));
```

MyRetryPolicy:

```
@Override
public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {
    Log.d("DEBUG", ""+error);
    // This is never getting called on NoConnectionError
}
```

The logging tells me "parseNetworkError" and after that "deliverError".

But i am not sure how to tell him to keep the request in queue until the network is back and the request can be passed through the server.

Does anyone know how to make it waiting for a positive response and retry it until getting it?

Or is there any better way for creating a queue of asynchrounus http requests than volley requestqueue?

Comment: where and how you are setting setRetryPolicy? you may want to show that code?

Comment: I tried with:

stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new MyRetryPolicy(20 * 1000, 5, 1.0f));

With my own RetryPolice Class.
But 

    @Override
    public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {
Log.d("DEBUG", ""+error);

is never getting called.

Updated my question above with that code...

Comment: I have found another question of the same issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628293/how-does-android-volley-handle-temporarily-loss-of-network-connection
But it isn't resolved yet, so the question is still: how to make the queue only delete entries on sucessful server transfer?

Comment: I will change it to create a "todo-Array" and on success, i update the todo-array. Then just looping thru that array with a timer makes it work.